# Download picture from a Gmail draft

Tags: gmail, iphone, gmail-attachments

I thought about a new and easy way to transfer a picture from my iPhone to my Desktop (without cable):

Attach the picture to a new Gmail mail (iPhone), open the draft (Desktop), copy the picture and paste it in Gimp.

However, opening the web-Gmail draft on the desktop, the pic is here, but there does not seem to be a way to "Save" or "Copy"... the picture. Selecting the pic, <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> or the menu "Copy" do not work. And I don't want an ugly screenshot...

Is there a way to download the picture in a web-Gmail draft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, found a way to do it (while still using a draft).

On the iPhone,

- click the [image] as usual to insert the image ; however, this is the default, and the image is loaded as part of the html mail, so, then
- tap the image, and select "Send as attachment"

  [image]
- ensure the draft is saved (try to close the draft, Gmail will tell you if it is not saved (Google servers side) yet)

and, voilà... opening the draft on the desktop web-Gmail the picture is now an attachment and can be worked with.

---

Edit 2023, comment from RichIV

> This feature has either been removed, or does not work from desktop. Alternate approach that works in 2023 - click on the vertical three dot icon, choose "Plain text mode". Pasting an image will add it as an attachment now.

Comment: This feature has either been removed, or does not work from desktop. Alternate approach that works in 2023 - click on the vertical three dot icon, choose "Plain text mode". Pasting an image will add it as an attachment now.

Answer (score 0):

Email the picture to yourself, or upload it to google photos.

Comment: I don't want to send an email each time I copy a photo, and don't use Google photos. Simply updating the draft, one draft, each time I need to transfer a pic.